# Make Docker Logs Persistent

Tags: docker, logging, docker-compose, docker-logs

I have been using docker-compose to setup some docker containers.
I am aware that the logs can be viewed using `docker logs <container-name>`.

All logs are being printed to `STDOUT` and `STDERR` when the containers are run, there is no log 'file' being generated in the containers.

But these logs (obtained from `docker logs` command) are removed when their respective containers are removed by commands like `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose rm`.

When the containers are created and started again there is a fresh set of logs. No logs from the previous 'run' is present.

I am curious if there is a way to somehow prevent the logs from being removed along with their containers.

Ideally i would like to keep all my previous logs even when the container is removed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have two ways you can go:

## Make containers log into file

You can reconfigure the applications inside the container to write into logfiles rather than stdout/stderr. As you put it, you'd like to keep the logs even when the container is removed. Therefore ensure the files are stored in a (bind) mounted volume.

## Reconfigure docker to store logs

Reconfigure docker to [use a different logging driver](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/). This can be especially helpful as it prevents you from changing each and every container.